# Solr partial match / EdgeNGram highlight

Tags: solr

Thanks for taking time to read through this.

I am using solr 6 to get the highlighter to work with EdgeNGramFilterFactory, the problem is that solr is returning the term matched, when what I want it to do is highlight the chars in the term that were matched.

The results that come back look like this:

`<em>Welcome</em>` to the Jungle

What I want them to look like is this:
`<em>Wel</em>come` to the Jungle

In my schema:

```
 <fieldtype name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="10"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldtype>

<field name="document" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Solr` return the text in highlight which is been stored in Solr`enter code here` index.

The indexing term like `Wel` which are been done by using the `analyser` used while indexing are not returned by it in any response.

In response you will get the original text if you have opted for `stored=true` for the same field.

So even though it matches the term `Wel`, it will return the original 
term/text in the highlight.